# Cannot create a new folder at project collection level in team explorer

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfvc, team-explorer

I am trying to create a new folder at project collection level from team explorer in Visual Studio but the option "New folder" appears disabled. Why is it not possible to create a folder at this level? however, I can create folders within team projects.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new Team Project in order for a folder to appear at that level.

The organization goes

- Team Project Collection

  - Team Project

    - Any folders you'd like to create via team explorer.

Comment: ok, it is not possible create folders at Team Project Collection level, only at team project level.